# Ошибка в next.Int()

Tags: java, ввод

При выполнении следующего кода (приведу только кусочек с проблемой)

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("How many account you want to verify");
        int countAccount = scan.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < countAccount; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter your login please");
            String loginPerson = scan.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter your id please");
            int idPerson = scan.nextInt();

            System.out.println(loginPerson + idPerson);
        }

    }
}
```

возникает следующая ошибка

```
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at main.main(main.java:19)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем ошибка? Вижу первый раз такое

Comment: Это не ошибка, а call-stack. А где ошибка?

Comment: Это весь код. Проблема именно в scan.nextInt()

Comment: @IvannaVasilkova, то что вы указали как текст ошибки - это не сама ошибка, а кусок "адреса", где возникла ошибка. Сама ошибка описывается в строках начинающихся с "Exception" (возникшее исключение) или "Caused by" (когда исключение вызвано другим исключением).

Answer (score 0):

Нашла такой ответ

```
System.out.println("How many account you want to verify");
    int countAccount = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    for (int i = 0; i < countAccount; i++) {

        System.out.println("Enter your login please");
         loginPerson = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter your id please");
        idPerson = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        System.out.println(loginPerson + idPerson);
    }
```